# LINQ how get max rating

Tags: linq, linq-to-entities

I have a model with the following entities:

```
Game: Id
User: Id
UserRating: Id, UserId, GameId, Value
```

Users can give a rating for a game.

I want to have a query that returns the top 5 games with the highest rating. The highest rating should be based on the Value, but when there are 2 or more games with the same rating, the count should also be taken into account.

How do express this in a query, return the result list as Game entities, using lambda expressions ?

(using EF 4, MVC, SQL Server).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume that by "highest rating" you mean "highest average rating"? It sounds like you want something like:

```
var query = from rating in db.UserRating
            group rating by rating.GameId into ratings
            orderby ratings.Average(x => x.Value) descending,
                    ratings.Count() descending
            join game in db.Game on ratings.Key equals game.Id
            select game;

var top5Games = query.Take(5);
```

EDIT: In non-query-expression form, this would be more painful, though still feasible:

```
var top5Games = db.UserRating
                  .GroupBy(rating => rating.GameId)
                  .OrderByDescending(ratings => ratings.Average(x => x.Value))
                  .ThenByDescending(ratings => ratings.Count())
                  .Join(db.Game, r => r.Key, g => g.Id, (r, g) => g)
                  .Take(5);
```

In this case doing it in the lambda syntax isn't *too* bad, as you're only getting the game out of the join... but more generally, it becomes nastier. It's definitely worth understanding and using both forms, depending on which is the simpler approach for the query at hand. In particular, when you start doing multiple joins it becomes *horrible* in lambda syntax.

Note that this won't give the rating for that game... to get that, you'd probably want something like:

```
select new { Game = game,
             RatingAverage = ratings.Average(x => x.Value),
             RatingCount = ratings.Count() }
```

at the end of the query instead of just `select game`.

Also note that you *may* want to exclude games which currently don't have enough ratings to be meaningful yet - otherwise a game with a single rating which is "perfect" will always be at the top.

EDIT: Okay, with the final tie-break of "name of game", I'd definitely use the query expression form:

```
var query = from rating in db.UserRating
            join game in db.Game on ratings.Key equals game.Id
            select new { rating, game } into pair
            group pair by pair.game into pairs
            orderby pairs.Average(x => x.rating.Value) descending,
                    pairs.Count() descending,
                    pairs.Key.Name
            select pairs.Key;

var top5Games = query.Take(5);
```

Comment: whow, fast Jon! How's is this query expressed in C# LINQ syntax style (aka .Join(x =>)?

Comment: @PatrickPeters: Why would you need to do so? Doing that would be painful... possible, but painful. You should always use whichever form will be more readable, which in this case would be the query expression form.

Comment: @PatrickPeters: I've added the translation - it's not too bad here as you don't actually need a transparent identifier, but I'd still use the query expression form this time.

Comment: +1 For the query expression syntax, too many people favour the chaining and in situations like this, it just looks like LINQ spaghetti.

Comment: @mattytommo: I find that the reverse is true, actually - I find too many people using query expressions when they really don't need to, particularly with LINQ to XML. Sometimes even with degenerate expressions: `from element in foo.Elements("xyz") select element`. Ick!

Comment: @JonSkeet Ah really? That is **equally awful**! I think when you get to joining/grouping you should use query expressions, for anything simpler, chain it! Would you agree?

Comment: Many many thanks Jon. I just want to return the list of games. The id's are needed in the MVC page to let the user click on a specific game where only the game id is relevant. I'll now add some unit tests to check the query in runtime.

Comment: @mattytommo: Yes, absolutely. Basically, everyone should be comfortable with both forms. The point at which to switch to query expressions is *usually* (IMO) the point at which the compiler would introduce a transparent identifier.

Comment: Works ok!! But little question extra: what if I have 2 different games, having the same rating ? I want the list to be sorted by game name then (which is part of the Game entity). Is that possible ?

Comment: @PatrickPeters: Yes, but it's slightly ugly - you'd need to do the join with the game table *before* you order by rating, so that you can order by rating, then rating count, then name.

Comment: Uhm... Jon.. I can't get the join earlier in query work correctly... can you re-edit the answer with the join on game to order by name as 3rd statement ? Thx!!

Comment: @PatrickPeters: Well is there anything else you're going to want to add to the requirements, before I do so? I'm not a big fan of continuously editing with different features...

Comment: @Jon: no, this is the only requirement extra

Comment: I prefer the non-query syntax, and rewrote the final query as: 

var query = entities.UserRatings
                .Join(entities.Games, ur => ur.GameId, g1 => g1.Id, (ur, g1) => new { Game = g1, UserRatings = ur })
                .GroupBy(g => g.Game)
                .OrderByDescending(games => games.Max(x => x.UserRatings.Value))
                .ThenByDescending(games => games.Count())
                .ThenBy(games => games.Key.Name)
                .Select(x => x.Key)
                .Take(5);
But the unit tests failed on the name sorting...

Comment: @PatrickPeters: Well without any information on how the unit tests work, or what the failures are, I don't think I can really help. I've given you the *logical* query - you should do the diagnostics to work out what else is happening yourself.

Comment: I tested it with LinqPad and the final query worked, but not in my fake entity sets. I'll research a little bit further, but the real code works ;-)